# How do I check the google analytics sdk version for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, version

I got some iOS projects that were developed by another company and I want to check what Google Analytics SDK versions are these projects using.

Note: When I run the projects, there's no google analytics logs showing the version

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not expert with google analytics but if you connect to the google analytics account it should tell you the version of the sdk which is receiving the data from no ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment, the problem is that the project has many targets, so the data is merged in the dashboard :(

Comment: u want to know which version of analytics sdk are used in the iOS project, correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the good answer, but you can identify the which version of **Google Analytics** added/used in your `Xcode` project.  open your **Google Analytics** folder in `navigator`  and open the **GAI.h**

inside the header file you get the `version`

```
 /*!
 @header    GAI.h
 @abstract  Google Analytics iOS SDK Header
 @version   3.0
 @copyright Copyright 2013 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
 */
```